# Set user account for a Windows service

Tags: windows, service

I have a batch file that installs a Windows service. The service needs to run under a specific user account. Does anybody know how to set the user account through the batch file instead of using the Windows "Services" GUI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change an existing service, use the `sc config` command. To change the "foo" service to use the "DOMAIN\User" credential with the password "password", execute:

```
sc config foo obj= DOMAIN\User password= password
```

Be sure to put spaces between the equals signs and the arguments.

If you're using `sc create` to create the service just add the `obj=` and `password=` arguments and you're done.